# What checks do you make to ensure correctness/consistency of a LaTeX generated research article?

Tags: bibliographies, pdf, proofreading

Of course, proofreading the entire article is the best way to catch errors in consistency, but often we submit articles very close to the deadline. Therefore, a list of standard quick checks would be helpful. Here are a few that I use:

1. Search for "?" in the PDF file for missing citations or references.
2. Search for "Section", "Figure", "Equation", etc. in the TEX file to ensure that they are followed by a non-breaking space (~).
3. Search the BIB file for ":" or "-" in the `title` field and capitalize the first letter after it by enclosing it in curly braces.
4. Search for specific conference/journal titles to check that all instances have the same format. For example, a reference may use "3rd Conference on Computing Methods" while some other uses "5th International Conference on Computing Methods".
5. The same check for the `publisher` field. For example, some reference may have "IEEE" while others have "IEEE Press".
6. ...

**What other checks do you use?**

Comment: Reading, reading, checking, reading... works ;-)

Comment: For 1. you can read the `log` file. Also, I search for ` ,` (blank space comma) to fix any occurrence of `foo , and so on`. The same for ` .` of course. Search for `\ref` to see if some should be replaced by `\eqref`. Search for `...` to replace by `\dots`.

Comment: @Sigur: It depends on the editor. On editors like Vim or Emacs were your can easily jump around by line numbers, the log file is useful. But in TexMaker and TexStudio, you would Ctrl+Click in the PDF to jump to source.

Comment: @Prometheus, yes, I know. But I mean that you don't need to search pdf for `?`. Just check the editor warning messages about citations. You can see them on some editor panel.

Answer (score 5):

You really need someone who is not the author to proofread the text. At the Boeing Company the professional proofreaders take about 20 minutes per page of technical literature!

It seems like you need to check your `.bib` file(s) for consistency. Why not use macros for references to Figures, etc. to ensure the non-breaking space. For example,less any typos:

```
\newcommand{\Fref}[1]{Figure~#1}
```

In the end it is the printed result that must be thoroughly checked.

Comment: Implementation of the referencing macros: [`cleveref` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/cleveref).